# What determines your chance to Flinch

Tags: diablo-iii

When playing (most often as melee) you'll often come across situations where when attacked your character will go through a "hit" animation, and cry out.  When you do this all your attacks (normal or special) are interrupted for a short time, however if you are surrounded by enemies, as you often are as melee, this can happen multiple times in a row; effectively stun locking you to death.  My question is what causes this to happen? And how can you avoid it?

Comment: Based on what you described it sounds like lag

Comment: No it's actually a game mechanic, it did exist in diablo 2, and you had to get gear that reduced the chance of this happening. They did carry this over to Diablo III, i am just needing to know the conditions that cause this.. If anyone knows the answer.

Comment: Dodge probably helps prevent it.

Comment: I play my Monk almost exclusively.  The only thing that stun locks me is Frozen and Nightmarish.  I'm pretty sure D3 doesn't have flinch mechanics.

Comment: @fbueckert I also played a Barbadian to Inferno Act 3 and never once has anything like that happened to me, which is why I think it's lag.

Comment: Yep, I main monk and have a level 60 of every class and I've never once had this happen to me.

Comment: Don't know if i can link this, but here's a set of posts discussing it, although it is not complete...https://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/5959626342?page=1 So the reason i know it's not lag, is because that casuses a stutter step, and my position resets,with or without other enemies on the screen.  Also i am on a pretty stable cable connection, and experience no issues with other games i play (World of Warcraft,Torchlight etc..)

Comment: Yeah, that's server lag; it sometimes has trouble keeping your position in sync between your computer and the server.  When that happens, if your position on your computer moves far enough from where the server thinks you are, it teleports you back to where the server thinks you're supposed to be.  No real way to prevent it, I'm afraid; Blizzard dropped the ball on this one.  They need to fix it.

Comment: Flinching isn't a mechanic in this game. It is definitely an issue with client/server sync. Not sure why people are so skeptical that that is the actual issue here.

Answer (score 3):

Based on your comment information, it sounds like the fairly common character desync issue.

Every now and then, where your computer thinks you are, and where the server thinks you are, are in two different locations.  This can be caused by several things, such as using movement abilities (Leap, Dashing Strike, Tempest Rush), or even just pausing the game in single player by hitting Escape, and then resuming later.

This causes not only the desync issue, but you'll also have trouble properly hitting enemies or avoiding damage spots, since your computer thinks you're at Point A, and the server thinks you're at Point B.  This can lead to some interesting situations where you think you're attacking an enemy, but not doing any damage.  Or you run out of their desecration patch, but you're still taking damage.  That's because the server thinks you're still at Point B; until you re-sync with the server, you can move all you want, but the server won't actually think you're moving.

In most cases, the de-sync happens in a radius around the point where you de-synced.  Leaving this radius usually causes the server and your computer to re-sync, which is your computer re-updating your position to where the server thinks you are.  That's the rubberbanding happening.  Rarely, this will not cause the computer to re-sync, leading to infinite rubberbanding, as you try to leave the area over and over.  In cases like this, I've found that those same movement powers that can cause a de-sync will allow you to re-sync.

The vast majority of this information just comes from my observations while playing, and experimenting when hitting the de-sync issue.  Once, I got de-synced while hung up on a chest; the rubberbanding was instantaneous, leading me to stutter in place.  The only way out was to use Dashing Strike; that got me off the chest, and continue playing.

Answer (score -2):

I have noticed this and died many times, because Revenge would not activate after pressing the key multiple times. This happens a lot because I put myself in a situation surrounded by enemies, or especially when getting hit by a ranged enemy. I assume this is because you are getting critically hit. Exactly the same as you critically hitting an enemy, any animation or attack they are activating is immediately stopped if you critically hit them. Obviously, you can counter this by stacking critical hit gear, but your barbarian skills like Overpower - Crushing Advance, Ground Stomp, Threatening Shout - Falter/Terrify and Leap will greatly minimize the occurrence, as well as any skill that has a "knock back".

Additionally, critically hitting a blue elite group has no affect in resetting their animation, but it does to unique groups and especially goblins when they are trying to flee!

Comment: This is untrue - critical hits (done to you or enemies) do not cause flinching; there are attacks that will break attack animations, but crits have nothing to do with it.

Comment: I disagree because flinching is breaking an attack animation and critical hits somehow affect them.

Comment: I've gotten crit numerous times.  Not once has it ever interrupted my attack animation.  The only time my attacks get interrupted is when I get knocked back, frozen, or feared.

Comment: On your character it seems random either by numerous hits, critical hits, or hard hits that activate this "flinch". I focused on the prevention, not the cause.

Comment: And again, I have never seen this flinching you speak of.  Every time it's happened, it's never been caused by number of hits, crits, or anything like that.  Some monsters have an attack that knocks your character back a little bit, that will interrupt your attack, but that has nothing to do with the damage received or number of times you got hit.  Think about it; if they had this ability, it would make melee character completely un-viable.  They'd run in, get stun locked, and die.

Comment: My Monk doesn't seem to have the Flinch issue but has the desync issue. My Barbarian doesn't seem to have the desync issue but the "flinch" occurs a lot. I think its specific to the Barbarian class.

Comment: Yes, what i am talking about generally happens when standing still,AND while in motion.  For instances i can be attacking a mob in melee, and not moving, and when another mob uses a ranged attack, my attack stops, if several enemies are attacking from ranged, i am stopped several times.  That's how i fairly sure it is not a lag issue.

Comment: @fbueckert , Actually yes this is what does happen, i've experimented over and again trying to recreate the issue, it's seems to be related to the hp you have, and how much of your total hp you take in damage in a single hit OR in a certian time frame, i am thinking it's a certain percent of your life in one second of time.  What i did to test this was deck my character out in as much life on hit as i could (2k+) but went to act 2 with only 15k hp.  Without fail, even though i had enough LOH to stay alive during being hit, i would in fact be stun locked, and die.

Comment: As I look around i think the proper term is called "hit recovery animation". Though i still haven't pinned it down yet, as it seems to be a hidden mechanic.